# android two buildTypes - error: duplicate class

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio 3.4

I have 2 build types:

```
debug
release
```

so my project structure is:

```
src/debug/java/

src/main/java/

src/release/java/
```

I has `CartActivity`. This class has different implementation for `release` version and `debug` version.
So this class location is in **TWO** folders:

```
src/debug/java/activityCartActivity
src/main/java/activityCartActivity
```

But when I build project by `gradlew assemble` I get error:

```
> Task :scanlib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :scanlib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug FROM-CACHE

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
\app\src\debug\java\com\myproject\app\cart\CartActivity.java:66: error: duplicate class: com.myproject.app.cart.CartActivity
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can't** do it.

```
src/debug/java/activityCartActivity
src/main/java/activityCartActivity
```

Check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourceset-build):

> **All source code in the java/ directories are compiled together to generate a single output.**

And in particular:

> **Note:** For a given build variant, Gradle throws a build error if it encounters two or more source set directories that have defined the same Java class. **For example, when building a debug APK, you cannot define both** **`src/debug/Utility.java` and `src/main/Utility.java`.** This is because Gradle looks at both these directories during the build process and throws a "duplicate class" error. If you want different versions of Utility.java for different build types, you can have each build type define its own version of the file and not include it in the main/ source set.

Answer (score 1):

Move CartActivity class from 'src/main/java/activityCartActivity' to src/release/java/activityCartActivity'.

"If above mentioned change does not work" modify java source path in app/build.gradle as

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            //java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/rs']
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = []
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = []
        }
        test{
            java.srcDirs = ['test']
        }
        debug {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/debug/java']
        }
        release {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/release/java']
        }

    }
```

Comment: Here solution: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourceset-build